# Renyi's theorem on mixing

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, operator-theory, ergodic-theory, mixing

I have been trying to understand the proof of Renyi's characterization of (strongly) mixing transformations:

A measure preserving transformation $T \text{ is strongly mixing iff for every measurable } A, \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \mu(A \cap T^{-n}A) \rightarrow \mu(A)^{2}.$

The only proof (sketched at the bottom) I've found uses the unitary operator $U_T$, and isn't especially enlightening (for me at least). I was wondering if someone could answer some questions about this for me?

1) Is there a proof of this characterization without mentioning $U_T$? Right now I am not even seeing a way to convert the proof using $U_T$ into a proof just involving sets. The main obstacle in this conversion seems to be the analog of decomposing an $L^2$ function $f$ into $f_1 + f_2$, where $f_1 \in M$ and $f_2 \in M^{\perp}$.

2) Are there many theorems which do not specifically mention the operator $U_T$, but whose proofs involve $U_T$ in ergodic theory? Is there any clear intuition on why the operator formulation is helpful? I suppose what I'm really asking is if there any sort of mechanical method of turning such a proof into one just involving sets, which (presumably) causes some large blowup in the length of proof?

Thank you very much, hopefully the questions weren't too vague.

*Sketch of proof* (See Peterson's Ergodic Theory):
The forward direction is trivial. For the backwards direction, fix a set $A$, and let $M$ be the linear subspace of $L^2$ generated by the constant functions and the set $\{U^k_T \chi_A \, | \, k\in \mathbb{Z}\}$. We can show that for every $f \in M$,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle U^n_T \chi_A, f \rangle = \langle \chi_A, 1 \rangle \langle f, 1 \rangle$.

Then for any $B$, we can decompose $\chi_B = f_1 + f_2$, where $f_1 \in M$ and $f_2 \in M^\perp$. By bilinearity,

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle U^n_T \chi_A, \chi_B \rangle = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle U^n_T \chi_A, f_1 \rangle + \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}  \langle U^n_T \chi_A, f_2 \rangle$.

The right most term is $0$, so

$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle U^n_T \chi_A, \chi_B \rangle = \lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} \langle U^n_T \chi_A, f_1 \rangle = \langle \chi_A, 1 \rangle \langle f_1, 1 \rangle = \langle \chi_A, 1 \rangle \langle \chi_B, 1 \rangle$,

where the last equality holds since $\langle f_2, 1 \rangle = 0$.

Comment: Something somewhat similar happens in the story of Szemeredi-type multiple recurrence theorems. Even though you’re interested in returns of a set to itself, the proofs go through decomposing L^2.

Comment: Thank you for the reference. I am reading the multiple recurrence section Einsiedler and Ward, and the proofs there have a lot of this reasoning. I have some hand-wavy informal reasoning why generalizing to operators and $L^2$ functions is a natural thing to do. Unfortunately, I can't convince myself that it is actually a natural thing to do, or what the underlying ideas of this machinery are.